# UILongGestureRecognizer not firing if slight movement by user

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

Currently I'm using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to add a function to a `UIButton` and then calling `setMinimumPressDuration:1` to call the function after the button is pressed down for 1 second. A problem I found, however, is that if the user so much as moves his finger half a centimeter while touched down over the button, it will not call the function.

In other words, the user has to basically stay touched down on one pixel for one second in order for the trigger to activate, even though the button is 100x100 pixels. This is pretty easy with a mouse, but becomes a problem on a physical device. Is there a way to fix this? I was thinking creating a trigger so that if a button has an alpha value < 1 for 1 sec it would call the function (when touched down the UIButton's alpha value is 0.75). How would I go about accomplishing that if there is no other way to repair the `UILongGestureRecognizer` problem.

Posting on a mobile device. Will fix any formatting problems/add code if needed as soon as I can get to my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Half a centimeter is pretty big on a mobile device. Is it possible they are moving their finger outside of the button's bounds before the gesture recognizer fires?

Comment: And adding method you call when the recognizer fires would be helpful.

Comment: @MikeD I just said half a centimeter to try to convey a small amount. However, if I'm on the simulator and hold down the mouse for 0.5s then move a pixel inside the button, the function will not fire at all. As for the actual function that's being called: it is pretty long. Too long to post write now on my phone. You can just assume it prints to NSLog or brings up an NSAlert. The problem is not in the function, it's in when the function gets triggered. Will update post if I ever get out of traffic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UILongGestureRecognizer` has a property called `allowableMovement` that's described on the documentation as "The maximum movement of the fingers on the view before the gesture fails."

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that property existed. Just checked really quickly and it seems to have solved my problem!